# Change the font in a wxPython StyledTextCtrl

Tags: python, fonts, wxpython, python-3.7, wxstyledtextctrl

I have been coding with wxPython and have run into a problem. I've created a `FontDialog` Function that also changes the font. The problem is that I am unable to change the font. In tkinter, you can `widget.config(font=font)` and the font changes instantly. I have been unable to figure out how to do that on a wxPython StyledTextCtrl. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my current code:

Define the widget:

```
self.control = wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
self.control.SetMarginWidth(1, 0)
self.control.SetScrollWidth(wx.stc.STC_CACHE_CARET)
self.CreateStatusBar()
```

Call the font function:

```
self._font = self.formatmenu.Append(wx.ID_SELECT_FONT, 'Font...', 'Change the font displayed in the editor')
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.font_func, self._font)
```

The function:

```
def font_func(self, event):
    dialog = wx.FontDialog()
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
        return
    font = wx.Font(dialog.GetFont())
    self.control.StyleSetFont(0, font=font) # Here is my error - nothing happens.
```

Thanks, Legorooj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that you are using `FontDialog` I think is simply returning the current font.
You need to access the `GetFontData` function, like so:

```
>>> dlg = wx.FontDialog(None)
>>> if dlg.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
...  font = dlg.GetFontData().GetChosenFont()
...  print(font.GetFaceName())
... 
Times New Roman
```